# Subsetting a Pandas.DataFrame object only where there is a difference between two rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering if it there were an easy way in python to return a subset of my DataFrame rows only where there is a change between two consecutive rows. For example, my dataframe object might look like this:

```
 Date            A     B
 20160713070000  20    21
 20160713070100  20    23
 20160713070128  20    23
 20160713070128  21    24
 20160713070134  23    24
```

In this case, I would want to return the following dataframe object:

```
 Date            A     B
 20160713070000  20    21
 20160713070100  20    23
 20160713070128  21    24
 20160713070134  23    24
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [drop_duplicates()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) function:

```
In [262]: df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A','B'])
Out[262]:
             Date   A   B
0  20160713070000  20  21
1  20160713070100  20  23
3  20160713070128  21  24
4  20160713070134  23  24
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe is df, try the following:

```
sub_df = df[df.groupby('Date')['A'].transform(lambda x: x.index[-1])==df.index]
```